# 2D integer array in c++ with uneven number of elements in each row

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, user-input, new-operator

The number of rows and columns of this array are given by the user however the number of rows are not the same (the array is uneven) and also the user will fill the array by entering the elements.

This is the code that I wrote but when I try to take input from user, the code crashes after taking some inputs. Please could you help me out and correct my code and point my flaws. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
//2d array
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int row;
    int col_x;
    cout << "Enter the row number:" << endl;
    cin >> row;
    //cout<<"Enter the column number:"<<endl;
    //cin>>col;
    int **a = new int *[row];
    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the column no.of array " << r << endl;
        cin >> col_x;
        a[r] = new int[col_x];

        cout << "Enter the elements in the array:" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < col_x; j++)
            {
                cin >> a[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout << "The elements in the array:" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < col_x; j++)
            {
                cout << a[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    delete[] a;
    a = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was an extra for loop. Also, you have to store the size of each row.
And make the proper deallocation of the 2D array.

```
#include <iostream>
//2d array
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int row;
    cout<<"Enter the row number:"<<endl;
    cin>>row;
    int **a=new int *[row];
    int *col_x = new int [row];

    for(int r=0;r<row;r++){
        cout<<"Enter the column no.of array "<<r<<endl;
        cin>>col_x[r];
        a[r]=new int[col_x[r]];

        cout<<"Enter the elements in the array:"<<endl;

        for(int j=0;j<col_x[r];j++){
            cin>>a[r][j];
        }
    }

    cout<<"The elements in the array:"<<endl;
     for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<col_x[i];j++){
            cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<row; ++i)
        delete[] a[i];
    delete []a;
    delete []col_x;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but the main issue with above code is, that you are accessing non-existing elements of your array. Maybe your loop over `r` should end in line 18? Even then, you would have to store the number of columns per row in some external variable. I would suggest to use a `std::vector` as the container instead of fixed arrays, in your case a `std::vector< std::vector<int> >`. The vector class has a method `size()` which stores its actual size.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are getting the input from the user is very vague, and is prone to accessing invalid memory. You are getting the same row many times in the inner loop.
Try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
 //2d array
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int row;
  int col_x;
  cout << "Enter the row number:" << endl;
  cin >> row;
  //cout<<"Enter the column number:"<<endl;
  //cin>>col;
  int ** a = new int * [row];
  for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
    cout << "Enter the column no.of array " << r << endl;
    cin >> col_x;
    a[r] = new int[col_x];

    cout << "Enter the elements in the array:" << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < col_x; j++) {
      cin >> a[r][j];
    }
  }
  cout << "The elements in the array:" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col_x; j++) {
      cout << a[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  delete[] a;
  a = NULL;
  return 0;
}
```

Also, note that `col_x` will hold only the size of the last row. So, it's not working for the printing at the end of  the code.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using C++, you should take advantage of the containers it provides for you to store your data, in this case a vector of vectors would be appropriate:

[Live Sample](https://onlinegdb.com/Bk5ZmlozU)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std; //<-- for test, souldn't be used

int main() {

    int rows, cols, temp;
    vector<vector<int>> matrix;

    cout << "Enter the row number:" << endl;
    cin >> rows;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        vector<int> v;
        cout << "Enter the column no.of array " << i << endl;
        cin >> cols;
        cout << "The elements in the array:" << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            cin >> temp;
            v.push_back(temp);
        }
        matrix.push_back(v);
    }
    cout << endl;
    for( auto i: matrix){   //print results
        for(int j: i)
            cout << j << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```